# How to skip unsupported image using cfimage processing?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml

I am using ColdFusion 10.
When trying to read some image files, ColdFusion returns no values and no error messages are shown.

I tried to re-size an image using **cfimage** tag. It is crashing. So I tried to get info about the image using **"imageinfo"** function. It returns blank. Please help me to either get some info or skip the image. Can anyone help me?

I tried reading the file which caused the anomaly using

```
<cfimage action="read" source="full pathname" name="image">
<cfset image = imageRead(full pathname)>
```

and many other ColdFusion documented functions. No error was shown. No output was obtained. I used cffile which showed unsupported file type error.

```
<cffile
    action = "readBinary" file = "full pathname" variable = "variable name"
>
```

Thanks Rino

Comment: Pls read this http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html and this http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/12/need-help-know-how-to-ask-for-it.html and this http://sscce.org/, and revise your question to include code that demonstrates what you're seeing, what the error messages are, and what you've already tried to sort the problem out for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this function for reading images.

`<cfimage>` tag or `imageNew()` can have issues while trying to read image files which are corrupted or files saved with changed extensions (background transparent .png files saved as .jpeg) while uploading.

I think the main problem with these files is that there is a chance coldfusion doesn't throw an error of any sort when we try to read files mentioned above.

```
<cfscript>
    public function readImage(fullpath){
        //trying java imageio
        var imageFile = createObject("java", "java.io.File").init(fullpath); 
        // read the image into a BufferedImage
        var ImageIO = createObject("java", "javax.imageio.ImageIO");
        try {
            var bi = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
            return ImageNew(bi);
        } catch(any e) {
        //try for bad formatted images
            //create java file object, passing in path to image
            var imageFile = createObject("java","java.io.File").init(fullpath);
            //create a FileSeekableStream, passing in the image file we created
            var fss = createObject("java","com.sun.media.jai.codec.FileSeekableStream").init(imageFile);
            //create ParameterBlock object and initialize it (call constructor)
            var pb = createObject("java","java.awt.image.renderable.ParameterBlock").init();
            //create JAI object that will ultimately do the magic we need
            var JAI = createObject("java","javax.media.jai.JAI");
            try {
                //pass in FileSeekableStream
                pb.add(fss);

                //use the JAI object to create a buffered jpeg image.
                var buffImage = local.JAI.create("jpeg", pb).getAsBufferedImage();

                //pass the buffered image to the ColdFusion imagenew()
                var New_Image = imagenew(buffImage);

                //make sure we close the stream
                fss.close();
                return New_Image;
            } catch (any e) {
                if (isDefined("fss")) {
                    fss.close();
                }
                rethrow;
            }
        }
    }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that while uploading image files if we change the file extension, that doesn't really change the mime type. I think this bizarre behavior ColdFusion is probably because its main priority is the file extension. Its better to read and write to a file type than change the extension and save.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Change the file extension how - via `cffile action="upload"`? Also, do mean you change the file content type?

Comment: I have seen this in some places where people just change the file extension to .jpg and save image files which are uploaded. `<cffile action="upload" destination="/path/to/some/directory/#createUUID()#.jpg" >`.

Which itself is a bad way to do things, and can complicate things when reading them. Proper validation should be used for file uploads, or else we can run into big troubles.

Comment: Agreed that is a flawed approach, but .. it is important to understand that action=upload simply "moves" and "renames" files. If you rename a file in windows, linux, etcetera to have the extension *.jpg, the file is not automatically converted into a jpeg. It is just renamed. So there is nothing "bizarre" about action=upload *not* changing the file content type either ;-)

Comment: by _"bizarre"_ I was taking about coldfusion not giving any error or even an output when trying to dump the variable which I try reading the file to.

Comment: (Not to hijack the OP's thread, but ..) Without an example, I am clear on which "variable" you are referring to here :) Can you give an example? You upload a PNG.  Save it with a different extension ie `destination="/path/to/some/directory/#createUUID()#.jpg`. Then what ... ?

Comment: @Leigh call `<cfimage action="read" source="full pathname" name="image">`.
And try to dump the variable. Please make sure the .png image is with a transparent background.